# SQL server user permissions audit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-administration

Below is the requirement for possibly a SQL-server dba

Come up with some process to audit who has access to what.  Might include:

1) Server login

2) Local admin

3) SQL server level roles, especially sysadmin

4) Database dbo, reader, writer

5) master,msdb access

6) linked server usage from a user account

7) Explicit grants on public
etc

Could someone please provide me how to achieve above

Thanks,
Sree

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to work with system tables/views. One of the primary tables (actually a view) will be `[master].[sys].[server_principals]`, where the users will be found.

You will also find `[master].[sys].[server_permissions]` to be useful, as it has permissions, and `[master].[sys].[server_role_members]` where you'll find roles. You'll find databases here `[master].[sys].[sysdatabases]`

Make note of the principalid, as it relates to the user.

Also in each database you'll find views such as `[Table].[sys].[sysusers]` and `[Table].[sys].[syslogins]`

You'll have to do your own work to get what you need for your application. You'll find a ton of information available online and in books regarding the above tables.

Answer (score 0):

I tried for my own question and below solved my purpose

```
set nocount on
declare @permission table (
Database_Name sysname,
User_Role_Name sysname,
Account_Type nvarchar(60),
Action_Type nvarchar(128),
Permission nvarchar(60),
ObjectName sysname null,
Object_Type nvarchar(60)
)
declare @dbs table (dbname sysname)
declare @Next sysname
insert into @dbs
select name from sys.databases order by name
select top 1 @Next = dbname from @dbs
while (@@rowcount<>0)
begin
insert into @permission
exec('use [' + @Next + ']
declare @objects table (obj_id int, obj_type char(2))
insert into @objects
select id, xtype from master.sys.sysobjects
insert into @objects
select object_id, type from sys.objects

SELECT ''' + @Next + ''', a.name as ''User or Role Name'', a.type_desc as ''Account Type'',
d.permission_name as ''Type of Permission'', d.state_desc as ''State of Permission'',
OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(d.major_id) + ''.'' + object_name(d.major_id) as ''Object Name'',
case e.obj_type
when ''AF'' then ''Aggregate function (CLR)''
when ''C'' then ''CHECK constraint''
when ''D'' then ''DEFAULT (constraint or stand-alone)''
when ''F'' then ''FOREIGN KEY constraint''
when ''PK'' then ''PRIMARY KEY constraint''
when ''P'' then ''SQL stored procedure''
when ''PC'' then ''Assembly (CLR) stored procedure''
when ''FN'' then ''SQL scalar function''
when ''FS'' then ''Assembly (CLR) scalar function''
when ''FT'' then ''Assembly (CLR) table-valued function''
when ''R'' then ''Rule (old-style, stand-alone)''
when ''RF'' then ''Replication-filter-procedure''
when ''S'' then ''System base table''
when ''SN'' then ''Synonym''
when ''SQ'' then ''Service queue''
when ''TA'' then ''Assembly (CLR) DML trigger''
when ''TR'' then ''SQL DML trigger''
when ''IF'' then ''SQL inline table-valued function''
when ''TF'' then ''SQL table-valued-function''
when ''U'' then ''Table (user-defined)''
when ''UQ'' then ''UNIQUE constraint''
when ''V'' then ''View''
when ''X'' then ''Extended stored procedure''
when ''IT'' then ''Internal table''
end as ''Object Type''
FROM [' + @Next + '].sys.database_principals a 
left join [' + @Next + '].sys.database_permissions d on a.principal_id = d.grantee_principal_id
left join @objects e on d.major_id = e.obj_id
order by a.name, d.class_desc')
delete @dbs where dbname = @Next
select top 1 @Next = dbname from @dbs
end
set nocount off
select * from @permission
```